# How to rotate a triangle around a point in JavaFX and get the value of the points?

Tags: java, javafx

How do I rotate a triangle (3 points) around one of the points?

I converted the triangle to a `Polyline`, created a `Rotate` with an angle and a point and used `.getTransforms(rotation)`.

Unfortunately this doesn't change the `Polyline` which I tried to convert back to a Triangle for further tasks.

```
Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
polyline.getPoints().addAll(
  resized.getVertexA().getX(),resized.getVertexA().getY(),
  resized.getVertexB().getX(),resized.getVertexB().getY(),
  resized.getVertexC().getX(),resized.getVertexC().getY(),
  resized.getVertexA().getX(),resized.getVertexA().getY()
);

Rotate rotation = new Rotate(alpha, start.getX(), start.getY());
polyline.getTransforms().add(rotation);

Tuple vertexC = new Tuple(polyline.getPoints().get(4),
  polyline.getPoints().get(5));
...
```

I expect to get x and y of point C, of the rectangular triangle with gamma being 90 degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know a way to do it in JavaFX, but you can use [Java2D](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) to do it:

```
double[] untransformedPoints = {
    resized.getVertexA().getX(), resized.getVertexA().getY(),
    resized.getVertexB().getX(), resized.getVertexB().getY(),
    resized.getVertexC().getX(), resized.getVertexC().getY(),
    resized.getVertexA().getX(), resized.getVertexA().getY()
};

double[] transformedPoints = new double[untransformedPoints.length];

AffineTransform rotation = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(
    Math.toRadians(alpha), start.getX(), start.getY());

rotation.transform(untransformedPoints, 0, transformedPoints, 0,
    untransformedPoints.length / 2);

Tuple vertexC = new Tuple(transformedPoints[4], transformedPoints[5]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea, unfortunately the line `rotation.transform(..);` produces the error index 8 out of bounds for length 8. So I tried to reduce `untransformedPoints.length()` by 3 and that works, 2 however not, which confuses me.

Comment: @flyby Oops, the last argument is the number of points, not the number of values;  I forgot to divide it by 2.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the transformed value of the points from your code in the below way as well:

```
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;

Rotate rotation = new Rotate(alpha, start.getX(), start.getY());
Point2D rotatedPoint = rotation.transform(resized.getVertexC().getX(),resized.getVertexC().getY());
```

Ofcourse I know that this value is not from the actual transformation, but computed separately.Just thought to let you know about this.

Comment: There is no `rotate` method in `Rotate` that takes 2 parameters or returns `Point2D`.

Comment: @fabian, thanks for correcting me. Yes it is 'transform' not 'rotate'. updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

The local coordinates do not change, if you add transforms. The coordinates in the parent coordinate system change.

You could use `Node`'s functionality to convert local coordinates to parent coordinates:

```
Point2D pointInParent = polyline.localToParent(polyline.getPoints().get(4),
                                               polyline.getPoints().get(5));
```

or use the `transform` method of the `Rotate` directly:

```
Point2D pointInParent = rotation.transform(polyline.getPoints().get(4),
                                           polyline.getPoints().get(5));
```